# ZeroTier and Heroku Dynos

Tags: heroku, devops, zerotier

I would like to connect Heroku dynos to external compute and storage resources (i.e. on-prem, multi-cloud, etc.)

Heroku Private and Shield have VPC peering with AWS, but introduces additional overhead.

Does ZeroTier work with Heroku dynos? If so, are there are any gotchas to be aware of?